# .NET Memory usage by module

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I have a silverlight application and using WCF to communicate to the backend SQL Server using entity framework.

I want to know what portion of my application is using the most memory. What tools can I use for uncovering memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) - Excellent Free Tool - can be used generically for any .NET application but i have never used it with Silverlight before so cant comment about the UI part.

[Red Gate's ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/) - Excellent paid tool including support for Silverlight.
I have used ANTS profiler in multiple ASP.net projects including WCF services and i have found it to be a very easy to use and definitely worth the money paid for it.